# Can I use TCP connection in my Office-JS addin?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I would like to connect to a TCP endpoint in my Excel Add-In. Can I do this using javascript and office.js in my addin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript in a browser (and, as a result, add-ins) cannot use TCP directly.

As an alternative, you can use web sockets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/